# Finding all combinations, pseudo

Tags: c#, pseudocode

I have 10 rows, each row can have 1-10 numbers with a value of 1-100 (the actual value doesn't really matter).   As an example, the first three rows will look like:

```
1. (2 numbers)                         1st 2nd 1st 2nd
2. (1 number)   all combinations --->  1st 1st 1st 1st
3. (2 numbers)                         1st 1st 2nd 2nd
```

With real numbers:

```
1. 5, 7                                5   7  5  7
2. 2            all combinations --->  2   2  2  2
3. 12, 24                              12 12 24 24

This results in a total of 4 unique combinations.
```

How can this be solved? I've tried for-loops and if statements, but it simply won't work as it should.

Comment: Are the numbers always unique, or might you have seven 42s?  Do you care that 1, 42, 42 looks very much like 1, 42, 42?

Comment: You didn't decide on the language yet?

Comment: @HABO I was told by Servy (see answear below) that it's called a Cartesian Product. The actual numbers will differ btw, but ranges from 1 to 100.

Comment: @skuntsel Well it's in C# but i needed the pseudo code to understand how to solve it :)

Comment: Let's try this again.  Say you have 10 rows with the following lists of values: ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1 ) and ( 1, 1 ).  We know that there are 1024 possible combinations, but they all look the same.  Is that expected?  Is it acceptable?  Is it impossible due to some restrictions on the inputs that you haven't mentioned?  Do you only want distinguishably different combinations?  If so, does the order matter, i.e. is ( 666, 42 ) different from ( 42, 666 ) for your purposes?

Comment: @HABO No the order doesnt matter at all. The 10 rows, and each row beeing able to hold 10 numbers. So the combinations are: How many numbers on Row 1 * How many numbers on Row 2... and so on. It's beeing called a Corthesian Product, so I'm trying to understand how that works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric Lippert wrote a *fantastic* article on how to write a method that can take any number of sequences, each of an arbitrary size, and find the Cartesian Product (that's the technical term for what you're asking for) of all of those sequences in C# .

[This is a link to that article](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)

The code that he derives at the end of the article is as follows, although I highly suggest reading the article to see how he ended up there:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

Simple example usage:

```
var array = new string[][] { new[] { "a", "b" }, new[] { "1", "2" } };
foreach (var product in array.CartesianProduct())
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", product));
```

Comment: Trying to get this to work, but i'm obvously doing something wrong... Was hoping the answear to my question wasn't this complex :/

Comment: @Half_Baked What are you trying, and what is happening?  Saying "it doesn't work" isn't enough for anyone to help you.  The method doesn't require any modifications; you just need to pass your data to it and then process the results however you need to.

Comment: I've given up on it. I have this complex linked class list X[0].Y[0].Z[0] and all data in Z[]. I need to rewrite it first. Do you have an example on how to format the argument for the above method?

Comment: @Half_Baked Just pass in a jagged array, or a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

An easy method using Linq in C#:

```
int[][] integers = ...
var results = 
    from row1 in integers[0]
    from row2 in integers[1]
    from row3 in integers[2]
    ...
    select new { row1, row2, row3, ... };
```

I think this is the simplest method, since you stated that there are always 10 rows.

Comment: @Half_Baked what's wrong with it? I tested it with your reduced test case and it worked exactly as expected. I only omitted indexes 3-9 for brevity, but there should be nothing different about that.

Comment: I mean, it's nothing wrong with your code. I just can't get it to work with my code... Trying to change this into List instead

Comment: So how would I get the query to execute? I mean getting the results?

Comment: @Half_Baked: Use `foreach` to get the results of a query.

Comment: @EricLippert Ah, that explains it!

Comment: @Half_Baked: As I have often said: If I could teach people just one thing about LINQ it is: the value of a query expression is *a query*, not *a result set*. Think of a query as assembling the words in a question; doing so does not ask the question, it produces the question to be asked.  Iterating the query "asks the question" and gets the answer.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Worked like a charm :) Did a regular for-loop inside the for-each loop to get out the values from the results array